# Model is null on JQuery submit

Tags: jquery, post, model-view-controller

I'm not much of a front-end web developer.  I prefer to work in the back-end, but I've been trying to resolve this for the best part of a day.

No matter what I try, the model is always empty.  If I change the 'save' button to type 'submit', it works fine but that just skips the confirmation dialog.

I whipped up a simplified MVC project (below) to highlight my issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried:

- $("#PersonalDetailsForm").submit();
- $("#PersonalDetailsForm")[0].submit();
- $("#PersonalDetailsForm")[1].submit();
- Using an ajax call
- Putting the confirmation modal inside the form and changing it to type 'submit'
- Renaming the model to 'model' (as per below)

Cheers

**Base View**

```
<div class="row">
    <a id="collectDetailsLink">Collect Personal Details</a>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="personalDetailsModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="personalDetailsModalContent"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#collectDetailsLink").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("PersonalDetails", "Home")',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#personalDetailsModalContent').html(data);
                    $('#personalDetailsModal').modal('show');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
                },
                cache: false
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Partial View**

```
@model JavaScriptFormPost.Models.PersonalDetailsModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("PersonalDetails", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "PersonalDetailsForm" }))
{
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="saveButton" value="Save" />
        <input type="button" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
}

<div id="confirmationModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div>Are you sure?</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="button" id="yesButton" value="Yes" />
                <input type="button" id="noButton" value="No" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#saveButton").click(function() {
            var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
            $('#confirmationModal').modal(options);
            $('#confirmationModal').modal('show');
        });

        $("#yesButton").click(function() {
            $("#PersonalDetailsForm :input").prop("disabled", true);
            $('#confirmationModal').modal('hide');
            $("#PersonalDetailsForm").submit();
        });

        $("#noButton").click(function() {
            $('#confirmationModal').modal('hide');
        });
    });

</script>
```

**Controller**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using JavaScriptFormPost.Models;

namespace JavaScriptFormPost.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult PersonalDetails()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PersonalDetails(PersonalDetailsModel model)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace JavaScriptFormPost.Models
{
    public class PersonalDetailsModel
    {
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you change it to type submit, it will skip your ajax call and go to default way of posting. What is the data return from your ajax call? Have u put a console log inside your ajax success to check whether it did return something? have you try to open ur browser developer tools(f12) to check whether the call is success?

Comment: The ajax call included above (as with the real one) has no issues.  It's the post that fails.

Comment: oh, ok, looking at the wrong item here, some question, is the  `$("#PersonalDetailsForm")` have anything? can u put a `console.log($("#PersonalDetailsForm"))` on your click event and check if there is such element 1st in your console, can you put out the html that generate by mvc too for a more actual view

Comment: It appears to know what PersonalDetailsForm is.  It highlights it on screen when I mouse over it in the console window.

Comment: Arrrrgh!! It's the _$("#PersonalDetailsForm :input").prop("disabled", true);_ line that nullifies everything.

Comment: OMG! It seems to work fine now.  I wasted a whole day on that!  I just moved this line to after the post.  Why didn't I try that earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested and as mentioned above, the $("#PersonalDetailsForm :input").prop("disabled", true); line was nullifying everything.  I moved it to after the call to submit and everything is now fine.

Answer (score 0):

Send data also in ajax as data: open curly brace
Name:$("#a").val(),
Lastname:$("#b").val()
End curly brace
Name and lastname should be same as in Model and in name property of any element

Comment: The actual model is more complex than first name & last name unfortunately.  It includes 4 variable size arrays that complicates things somewhat... it does for a JavaScript dunce like anyway.